# Xcode 6.1 doesn't "detect" framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, backend

I'm building an app for iOS 8, which worked great - but after I moved the project around, it doesn't seem to work properly. It doesn't seem to "detect" the frameworks, while I can actually import the class in code, I can't use any of the functionalities provided with it.

I've tried to delete the frameworks and re-add the a hundred times. This is what Xcode looks like:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks a lot!
Erik

**Update**
[image]

Comment: You need the ParseUI framework for the PFQueryTableViewController. http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/06/introducing-the-new-parseui-for-ios/

Comment: Added it now, still reports same error :/ @Fogmeister

Comment: Yup, now you need to import it. `#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>`

Comment: @Fogmeister did that now as well, still doesn't see it :/

Comment: Yeah, you removed the `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` line...

Comment: Also, just use Cocoapods. It makes everything much easier.

Comment: @Fogmeister The bottom picture is the implementation file and the upper one is the header file. I put the #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> in the implementation file and not the header file. Works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ParseUI.framwork seems to be missing. You need to import that as well. from the parse SDK folder drag ParseUI.framework, and make sure that is listed in project dependencies.

Comment: I was facing the same problem, and I fixed it using the solution I mentioned above.